# How to define a Flow type for an object that must have at least one of the properties?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following object declaration:

```
type QueryQuantifierType = {
  +max?: number,
  +min?: number,
  +multiple?: boolean
};
```

It permits:

```
{
  min: 1
}

{
  max: 1
}

{
  max: 1,
  min: 1
}

{
  min: 1,
  multiple: true
}

{
  max: 1,
  multiple: true
}
```

These are valid values.

However, the problem is that it also [permits an empty object](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCKArngE5YkCGAdhgJZT3kAquBAvGAN6phgBqALZUAHgH4AXGBrEhAI3IAaPoKH0aUmXMVkV-YcRgMcMPFvlw4Z2qgC+AbnQBjODQDOGMAEditBkzk0iTklH50jMxkbPhgXNyOQA).

How to define a Flow type for an object that must have at least one of the properties?

Answer (score 4):

The only way I have figured out how to do this is using a [union](https://flowtype.org/docs/union-intersection-types.html) of [exact](https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#exact-object-types) objects:

```
type QuantifierType =
  {|
    +max: number,
    +min?: number,
    +multiple?: boolean
  |} |
  {|
    +max?: number,
    +min: number,
    +multiple?: boolean
  |} |
  {|
    +max?: number,
    +min?: number,
    +multiple: boolean
  |};
```

Comment: For the record, there is a bug (probably) associated with this approach when using `Infinity` as a `number` value. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3296

Comment: Did you find a modern way to do this? Also what does the `+` prefix mean?